# Intellij idea choose implementation of class/trait action shows two times more results

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

If I have both binary files and sources downloaded and press icon to see who implements some trait or class, idea shows me a list with each child mentioned 2 times - one it takes from sources and another from binary. This isn't a big problem but sometimes irritates me)

*Here you can see implemetation in binary files (blue) and sources (red).*

[image]

Is there a way to make this implementation list *distinct* and still have both binary and sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9124
However I just fixed it.